# How do I `drawtext` video playtime (“elapsed time”) with `:`s on a video in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

### Question

How do I `drawtext` video playtime (“elapsed time”) on a video, with *FFmpeg*'s `--filter_complex` option?

### Example

Assuming I have a video whose duration is 150 seconds:

- Elapsed 1 second since the video started: the video displays `00:01 / 02:30`.
- Elapsed 2 seconds since the video started: the video displays `00:02 / 02:30`.
- Elapsed 3 seconds since the video started: the video displays `00:03 / 02:30`.

Comment: Have you checked the `drawtext` options, specifically the text expansion and `pts` (presentation timestamp)?  http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion

Comment: @slhck Thank you. But I have no idea how to format it like above. `%{pts\:SS}`, `%{floor(pts)}`, `floor(%{pts})`, `%{floor(%{pts})}` don't work. I'd appreciate it if you help me.

Comment: `hms` is too verbose; I don't need the `HH` part.

Comment: I DID IT! `text = '%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\\\:%S}'`; this is insane!

Comment: Wow, okay, that's a lot of escapes. Feel free to post this as an answer to your own question! Note that no complex filter is needed, just `-vf "drawtext=…"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [a same question on *Video Production* *Stack Exchange*](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21905/how-to-set-pts-time-format-when-using-ffmpeg-filter-to-add-timestamp/22590#22590). I figured out how to do this, basically like this:

```
drawtext = text = 'Timestamp\: %{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\:%S}.'
```

From Bash, with weak quotes:

```
-filter_complex "drawtext = text = '%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\\\:%S}'"
```

More details [are here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22590/20276).